# JSObject to JSArray

Tags: vb.net, jsobject

I'm trying to read all URLs from a html document.

I am using the following code:

```
    Dim html As String =
                                    "var linksArray = new Array(); " &
                                    "for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {" &
                                    "linksArray[i] = [String(document.links[i].innerHTML), String(document.links[i].innerText), String(document.links[i].href)];" &
                                    "} " &
                                    "return linksArray;"

    Try
        Dim linksArray As JSObject = _Browser.WebView.EvalScript(String.Format("(function(){{ {0} }})()", html))

        If linksArray Is Nothing Then
            Stop 'this line is not reached, so it should be fine so far
        End If

        'the following line throws an error
        Dim urls As JSArray = linksArray.ToArray()

        For Each link As JSObject In urls
            Dim sInnerHTML As String = link(0).ToString().Trim()
            Dim sInnerText As String = link(1).ToString().Trim()
            Dim sHRef As String = link(2).ToString().Trim()

            If sHRef <> "undefined" Then

                Dim nItem As New clsURL
                nItem.HRef = sHRef
                nItem.InnerHTML = sInnerHTML
                nItem.InnerText = sInnerText

                nList.Add(nItem)
            End If

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message.ToString)
        Stop
    End Try
```

However, the line

```
 Dim urls As JSArray = linksArray.ToArray()
```

throws the error "The object reference was not set to an object instance".

Does anybody know how to do it correctly?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What Do you See when you Monitor "linksArray"?

Comment: @etalon11 I have added a screenshot to my post.

Comment: Can you please Monitor one item? Also "urls" is not declared as an Array. You cant convert a normal Array to JSArray, or?

Comment: Sorry, can you please explain more in detail what you require to see? No, I can not use a normal array unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
        Dim linksArray As JSArray = _Browser.WebView.EvalScript(String.Format("(function(){{ {0} }})()", html))

        For Each obj As Object In linksArray

            Dim sInnerHTML As String = obj(0).ToString().Trim()
            Dim sInnerText As String = obj(1).ToString().Trim()
            Dim sHRef As String = obj(2).ToString().Trim()

        Next
```